# How to display a set number of rows in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How do i display set number of rows in a UITableView?

i.e if my data source has only 4 objects then i want the table to display on those 4 rows without any blank rows. any ideas?

thanks!

EDIT: i wasn't too clear about the question so..

So this is my table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glkWZ.png ..
i want to display only the 3 rows and not the blank rows below it. The number of rows change depending on my data source.
any ideas how to go about doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your table appearance, I think. Once you correctly set the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods, you should change your `viewDidLoad` method adding this line:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

This way you will remove all lines from the table.

If you still want to make a line appear between lines, I suggest you to create a custom `UITableViewCell`, or to build a standard one adding a subview to mimic the line. Eg. something like this:

```
CGRect lineFrame = CGRectMake(0,cell.frame.size.height-1,cell.frame.size.width,1);
UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:lineFrame];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1];
[cell.contentView addSubview:line];
[line release];
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: But this code just removes the Separator line right? How do i get rid of the blank table view cells ?

Comment: You already have an empty table! The problem is that you defined a gray background for the table, so everything appears gray. I think that you should do something different: use a clear color or white color as table background, and set a gray background for each cell. This will work, I suppose.

Comment: ah i now get what you're saying. 
basically its a workaround whereby you remove the line seperator and keep the colour of the view background same as that of the table View so that it looks like there are no rows present.
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check the UITableView DataSource [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource), there are two relevant methods you have to implement:

```
– numberOfSectionsInTableView:
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

The first one should return 1, the second one 4.

Comment: I'm sorry but i wasn't very clear with my query. So this is my table: http://i.imgur.com/glkWZ.png ..
i want to display only the 3 rows and not the blank rows below it. 
any ideas how to go about doing so?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep a set number of lines in your tableview and not display the extra blank lines, you could insert a empty footer view in viewdidload function.

`self.tableview.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`

Answer (score 1):

I did not actually understand what you mean with "display on those 4 rows without any blank rows" but I guess what you ask is just a simple data retrieval process. I suppose the data source is NSarray.

```
-numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return [MyArray count];
}

-cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
       NSInteger row=indexPath.row;
  cell.textLabel.Text=[MyArray objectAtIndex:row]
  return cell;
 }
```

I assume you know what should be put in those blank spaces.I just wrote the major points.

Comment: I'm sorry but i wasn't very clear with my query. So this is my table: http://i.imgur.com/glkWZ.png ..
i want to display only the 3 rows and not the blank rows below it. 
any ideas how to go about doing so?

Comment: @ Praveen S I know I did not provide the full name of the methods after the - sign. I just wanted note which method.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
   {
   return 4
   }
```

also implements the rest of delegate methods required to populate tableview..

Hope it helps you.......

Comment: I'm sorry but i wasn't very clear with my query. So this is my table: http://i.imgur.com/glkWZ.png ..
i want to display only the 3 rows and not the blank rows below it. 
any ideas how to go about doing so?

Comment: change the height of your rows so that only three rows are visible

Answer (score -2):

You can use this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
   {
   return 4
   }
```

Or you this also
Check the UITableView DataSource protocol, there are two relevant methods you have to implement:

> – numberOfSectionsInTableView:
>     –
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

The first one should return 1, the second one 4.

Or you can also use
`GroupBy` table in your view  by changing the table style to gourpby  table. use